# Adding page breaker via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add [page braker](https://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks) to the end of each html part, here is my code:

```
printHtml += '<div id="#pageBraker">end of current page</div>';
$("#pageBraker").css("display","none");
$("#pageBraker").css("display","block");
$("#pageBraker").css("page-break-before","always");
```

And in the end of each part I see `end of current page` with no console errors.
My question are:

1.How to add `@media` to my `pageBraker` or to my HTML?

2.Is this the right way to insert dynamically?

Here is my entire code:

```
//elemsToPrint - list of elements I want to print but with page breaker between
for (var index = 0; index < elemsToPrint.length; index++) {
    printElement = elemsToPrint[index];
    printHtml += $(content).parent().html();
    printHtml += '<div id="#pageBraker">end of current page</div>';
    $("#pageBraker").css("display","none");
    $("#pageBraker").css("display","block");
    $("#pageBraker").css("page-break-before","always");
    //send to printer
    _printElement(printHtml);
}
```

The end goal is that each part(`printHtml`) will be printed in separate page.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can't duplicate ids on a single page man.  Ids must be unique.  Regardless of if that is your issue or not, use a class instead if the identifier is non-unique.

Comment: adding .css is not the way to add class?

Comment: I am new with jQuery....

Comment: learn.jquery.com try.jquery.com <-- give them a read

Comment: still how can I add @media to my dynamically?

Comment: You don't add @media with jquery.  You create your stylesheets ahead of time that contain the media rules, and then you change your elements to match the criteria that the media targets.

Comment: Thank you! I will have a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to apply any styling in your `for-loop` for this. Instead, do it within a stylesheet:

```
#pageBraker {
  display: none;
}

@media print {
  #pageBraker {
    display: block; 
    page-break-before: always;
  }
}
```

Here you're using the `@print` media query which only applies this particular styling in the print view. Outside of the print view, `#pageBraker` won't show.